# CKFinder Javascript api to add folders

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckfinder

I want to add a additional parent level folder to CKFinder object.

Current setup:
On Create: `/resource/events/0/`
On Edit: `/resource/events/{id}/`

Wish On Edit:

```
{'/resource/events/{id}/', '/resource/events/0/', '/resource/shared/'}
```

The multiple folders solution will help in reducing the need to upload the same file on many events.

An ASP solution talks about adding the "`ResourceTypes(3)`" definition to add more sub-folders, but I am unable to find documentation on JavaScript API solution.

> Unresolved Q&A:
>   http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/Multiple-Images-folders